# Laravel eager loading combine where for multiple tables

Tags: sql, laravel, eager-loading, eloquent

I have problem with Laravel eager loading, I want to search many to one related tables.

I have two models, Book and Author.
I have relation belongsTo (in Book model) and hasMany (in Author model).

```
Books: id, title, description, author, tags, type
Author: id, name, birth, tags, type
```

(this is not the real columns, I have a lot of columns, this is only for example)

I must to use models for searching, I can't use DB or raw queries for the relations.

So, my question is how can I search by parent table into Model->with() function ?

```
Model->with('author', function($query) use($search) {
    $query->where('author.name', '=', $search);
    $query->orWhere('book.title', '=', $search);
});
```

The important thing is that I need to get Books, and I must to be able to use $book->author (or on $results->toArray() to get all Book data with Author data in ->author property)

I hope that you understand me what I want to ask.

Best regards

Comment: Did you try joining the two tables?

Comment: Yes, but in that case I don't know how to convert the results to be standard Book model. After getting the results I need to be able to use Model features.

Comment: So you want to get all Books (and their authors), where either author.name matches `$search` or book.title matches `$search`?

Comment: If you are querying with `\App\Book::where`, you'll get a `\App\Book\` collection from your query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to search by author name and `orWhere()` to also search by book title:

```
Book::whereHas('author', function($q) use($search) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->get();
```

So, this query will find all books with defined title or author's name. If you also need to load the author data, add `->with('author')` to the query.

Comment: But what if I want to get something like that:
book.year = 2017 AND book.publisher = something AND ((book.title = $search OR authour.title = $search) AND author.awards = something)

I have several parameters that use AND operator, and $search parameter that should be group of OR operators.

Comment: @DamjanKrstevski you didn't mention any of that in your question. Just add any conditions to the query and use [`where()` closures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping) to group parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use **with** to eager load the author and **whereHas** to filter the records.

```
Book::with('author', function($query) use($search) {
    $query->where('name', '=', $search);
})->whereHas('author', function($query) use($search) {
    $query->where('name', '=', $search);
})
 ->where('title', '=', $search)
 ->get();
```